# WSO2 ESB: how to carry a SOAP answer into a file (or DB) using a scheduled task

Tags: web-services, proxy, scheduled-tasks, store, wso2-esb

I deploy a proxy service in WSO2 ESB that asks a web service for a dataset by a SOAP request and the web service correctly returns the requested dataset. In order to have evidence of the right answer of the web service, how can I do to store this dataset into a generic file during a regular scheduling in a task?

Comment: Why don't you save this dataset in a file as soon as you receive the response from your webservice ? what does this scheduled task has to do with your need ?

Comment: That's what i want to do. I'd like to know what an expert of WSO2 ESB would do in order to save the file: clone mediator, store mediator and so on, I don't know which of this tool is more useful. I don't want to implement a custom client for do this, and that's the reason for WSO2 choice.

Comment: I directed the return message from web service in a message store of WSO2 ESB, simply creating a new message store and adding a Store Mediator to the service proxy. This is a good step, now i want to transfer it into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proxy def, you can find :

- a inSequence executed when a request is sent to this proxy,
- a outSequence that receive a response if you send a request from your inSequence (with send mediator)
- a faultSequence executed if an error occurs.

So, if you "asks a web service for a dataset" from your inSequence using send mediator, your outSequence receive the response (your "dataset") and you just have to send it to a file :

```
<!-- name of the file -->
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="dataset.xml" scope="transport"/>
<!-- OUT_ONLY because we want to use send mediator but don't want a callback waiting for a response -->
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" />
<!-- Send current message (the response from your webService) to the filesystem : test directory must exist on c:\ -->
<send>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/test"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

--> don't forget to activate VFS sender in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml : uncomment `<transportSender name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender"/>`

Comment: Well, i did, it, now i can copy the dataset into a file. I scheduled it in a task setting the soap message, the proxy name, the soapAction and the format. Thank You

Comment: It does not work again... i can't understand why. With SOAPUI it works well, the same message in a task doesn't work properly, i have the response "HTTP header value is not recognized by the server SOAPAction: QueryStructure." I can't understand why, i set "message", "proxy name" "inject to" "soap action" "format".

Comment: I tried to operate with a different proxy service and a different web services, so now the esb gives me the same response: "HTTP header value is not recognized by the server SOAPAction: xxxx" where xxxx is the soap action name. What changed??? In "try this service" the service works good, also in SOAPUI setting the endpoint of the WSO2 ESB endpoint... the problem is in the task, every task.

Comment: I also put a dedicated question on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385456/soap-action-error-in-wso2-esb-task-configuration/31399196?noredirect=1#comment50903993_31399196

Comment: I think there could be an error due to a broken task class... last week it worked fine, i really change nothing and now it doesn't work. Anybody knows how to restore the right task class in the WSO2ESB?