# Soap Action error in WSO2 ESB Task configuration

Tags: web-services, soap, proxy, scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb

I have deployed a WSO2 ESB Proxy Service that works well: it sends a request for a dataset, in the outSequence of the proxy service I send response in a file (I set a sequence for doing it) and i can also visualize response in SOAP UI (or in the "try this service" page of the ESB).

If I set a scheduled task it doesn't work: i set message (my xml right-working message in SOAP UI), injectTo (proxy), proxyName (my proxy name), format (my format) and SoapAction...

I'm sure that the name of SoapAction is correct, but the response of the server is "HTTP header value is not recognized by the server SOAPAction: xxxx" where xxxx is the right soap action name.

This happens with another task i've tried using another simpler proxy service, everything is correct until I use the proxy service within a scheduled task. 
I can't understand.

Comment: I think there could be an error due to a broken task class... last week it worked fine, i really change nothing and now it doesn't work. Anybody knows how to restore the right task class in the WSO2ESB?

Answer (score 2):

You must be add "soapAction" header like this:

```html
<property name="Code" value="1234"/>
                <header name="soapAction" scope="transport" value="http://tempuri.org/MyService/GetAddress"/>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <soapenv:Envelope
                            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                            <soapenv:Header/>
                            <soapenv:Body>
                                <tem:GetAddress>
                                    <tem:Code>$1</tem:Code>
                                </tem:GetAddress>
                            </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Code')"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address format="soap11" uri="http://192.168.1.1/Services/ShakouriService.svc?wsdl"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you receive this error in the insequence or the outsequence..
Plus, when you send a response back are you using `<send/>` or providing a specific endpoint.

Comment: Every invoked webservice returns me the response explaining that the soap action is not recognized, i think the problem is in the inSequence because the outSequence works in the right way: sends the answer of the webservice to a file "example.xml" and, by a "core-send" added in the outSequence, i can see the result in the console.

Comment: "Unable to handle request. The action 'CodiceComune' was not recognized". I insert the same soap message that obtains a right answer with SOAPUI through the esb... i can't understand. Fields are proxy, inject to, message xml, soapAction and format, each of them is correct.

Comment: try to add the action inside the inSequence using a header mediator.
and in the scheduledTask  soapAction field add the action that you see in your proxy service wsdl.

Comment: Thank you, but what kind of header should I put in the header mediator for describing the action?

Comment: use this:
<header name="Action" scope="default" value="CodiceComune"/>

Comment: Nothing. "Try this service" works, SOAPUI request works, but task doesn't work. I can't understand where is the problem. The problem is always the same: every time i schedule a task, the remote service cannot recognize the soapAction. Maybe the task class is corrupted???

Comment: try using log mediator at the start of the insequence of your proxy and check what action are you receiving